# What is Difference between HashMap and SplayTreeMap in Dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand the difference between the `HahsMap` and `SplayTreeMap` in Dart.

I already went through the [official dart docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html) to understand the difference, but I found that `HashMap` and `SplayTreeMap` seems to be working in the same way (Although I am sure they are not the same and `SplayTreeMap` works based on the concept of `Self Balancing Binary Tree`).

I tried following sample code in order to understand the difference, but I am getting the same output.

**Sample code**

```
void main() {
  HashMap hashMap = HashMap();
  hashMap[4] = 'Apple';
  hashMap[2] = 'Banana';
  hashMap[3] = 'Mongo';
  hashMap[1] = 'Grapes';
  print('HashMap : $hashMap');


  SplayTreeMap splayTreeMap = SplayTreeMap();
  splayTreeMap[4] = 'Apple';
  splayTreeMap[2] = 'Banana';
  splayTreeMap[1] = 'Grapes';
  splayTreeMap[3] = 'Mango';
  print('SplayTreeMap : $splayTreeMap');
}
```

**Output**

```
HashMap : {1: Grapes, 2: Banana, 3: Mongo, 4: Apple}
SplayTreeMap : {1: Grapes, 2: Banana, 3: Mango, 4: Apple}
```

It seems that, `HashMap` and `SplayTreeMap` both the data structure are ordering the element based on the `key` order.

Kindly let me know the exact difference between `HashMap` and `SplayTreeMap`. It would be great if you can provide an example code which can highlight the difference between `HashMap` and `SplayTreeMap`.

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the documentation you cited, with some emphasis added:

> - The plain HashMap is unordered (**no order is guaranteed**),
> - the LinkedHashMap iterates in key insertion order,
> - and a sorted map like SplayTreeMap **iterates the keys in sorted order**.

A `HashMap` simply does not *guarantee* any specific order.  It could happen that entries are iterated over in some order that appears sorted, which is what happened in your example.  If you tried other examples with less trivial keys or with more entries, you almost certainly would observe different results.  For example, if you inverted your keys and values:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var hashMap = HashMap<String, int>();
  hashMap['Apple'] = 4;
  hashMap['Banana'] = 3;
  hashMap['Mango'] = 2;
  hashMap['Grapes'] = 1;
  print('HashMap : $hashMap');

  var splayTreeMap = SplayTreeMap<String, int>();
  splayTreeMap['Apple'] = 4;
  splayTreeMap['Banana'] = 3;
  splayTreeMap['Mango'] = 2;
  splayTreeMap['Grapes'] = 1;
  print('SplayTreeMap : $splayTreeMap');
}
```

with Dart 2.18.2 for the web, I get:

```
HashMap : {Apple: 4, Banana: 3, Mango: 2, Grapes: 1}
SplayTreeMap : {Apple: 4, Banana: 3, Grapes: 1, Mango: 2}
```

(Note that your `HashMap` results might vary with different target platforms or different Dart SDK versions.)

Additionally, `HashMap` and `SplayTreeMap` have different runtime performance. `HashMap` is a hashtable and thus has amortized O(1) lookup, insertion, and removal.  In contrast, `SplayTreeMap` is a search tree and therefore has amortized O(log n) lookup, insertion, and removal.